# BIRT how to show a set of columns on demand for every row of report

Tags: java, birt

We have a  requirement where we have to show thousands of events in a BIRT report. Each event record is going to have 5 rows of grouped info. I feel that if the extra info that comprise the 5 rows are hidden by default and shown only on request, then the report can at least show a month of report. E.g. If columns 1 to 5 are repeated per event record, columns 6 to 10 contain extra info that has distinct values per event record spread across 5 rows. I want to show only columns 1 to 5 by default but columns 6 to 10 to be shown only on demand , like on click of a control element like drill down. If columns 6 to 10 are shown by default per event record, report runs to atleast 1000 pages for a single month, which is not very useful. I tried the Hyperlink option (drill-down report) but it results in a round trip to server which does not look good. The Internal bookmark option seems plausible but I could not find an example as detailed as my requirement. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks,
Paddy

Comment: It looks like a typical drill-down requirement, what do you mean by "which does not look good"? This detail report should be super-fast

Answer (score 0):

You don't say but I am assuming you are talking about a BIRT report that opens as a web page with Apache.

There is **No** option in BIRT to open a web report with some data present but hidden.  To click and show more data (drill down) you will need to go to the server to get the rest of the data.